# Can I use another database's table in postgresql, yet give an impression the table exists in the same database?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Say I have the following database hosts

1. `core` (host: `a.b.c.d`, dbaname: `core`, username: `coreUser`) with tables `users`, `accounts` and `permissions`
2. `app1` (host: `d.e.f.g`, dbname: `appdb1`, username: `appuser1`)
3. `app2` (host: `h.i.k.l`, dbname: `appdb2`, username: `appuser2`)

I would like `core.users`, `core.accounts` and `core.permissions` to be available as native tables on `app1` and `app2`. I want to be able to mirror the exact table and inserts and updates on these tables should update the tables in the `core`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) can do the job.

> The postgres_fdw module provides the foreign-data wrapper
>   postgres_fdw, which can be used to access data stored in external
>   PostgreSQL servers.
>
> The functionality provided by this module overlaps substantially with
>   the functionality of the older dblink module. But postgres_fdw
>   provides more transparent and standards-compliant syntax for accessing
>   remote tables, and can give better performance in many cases.

FDW as you know stands for foreign data wrappers, it's used to connect external data sources to postgresql. In this case the external data source is another postgrsql database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look at [slony replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slony).

If you don't want to copy data then [dblink extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/dblink.html) might help you. It allows to call queries from one database to other. Combined with a function or a view could potentially be useful (although changes done to `core` would not be automatically reflected in "child" databases).